# Modifying Browser Root Color Palettes

Tags: html, css, browser

Is it possible to change the root color palette of a browser on a certain page?

For example.

```
<div style="color:blue">Blue Text</>
```

color: blue => color:#0000FF (browser assume)

I want to tell the browser that "blue" is #0000BB. (either through stylesheet.css or javascript modifying its default palletes )

Plus, is it possible to add more standard color to the pallete? 
Like: navyblue => #3e3e80

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's possible to overwrite the root colour palette itself, but what you **can** do is make use of **[custom CSS properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables)** to achieve almost the same thing.

Simply define the colours that you want in the `:root`, using `--` as a prefix. You can then reference these colours by using `var(--variable)` as the `color` value.

This can be seen in the following:

```css
:root {
  --blue: #0000FF;
  --navyblue: #3e3e80;
}

div {
  color: var(--blue);
}

span {
  color: var(--navyblue);
}
```

```html
<div>Blue</div>
<span>Navy Blue</span>
```

Using CSS variables in this way allows you to easily change a colour throughout the entire site by only changing one line of code, and also allows for additional colours to be easily mapped out.

Comment: Is that -- prefix required? It looks kinda of strange :O

Comment: Yes, it is required; it's how CSS variables work. SASS, LESS and other precompilers use the `@` symbol, but `--` will work for raw CSS :)